# Unity Object Pool Objects Invisible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object-pooling

The following code below shows what I made. (Pooled square is a game object I set up in another c# file)

```
[SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;
private List<GameObject> PooledSquares = new List<GameObject>();
private Camera cam;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)) {

        Vector3 MousePosition = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        GameObject pooledSquare =  ObjectPool.SharedInstance.GetPooledObject();

        if (pooledSquare != null)
        {
            pooledSquare.SetActive(true);
            pooledSquare.transform.position = MousePosition;
        }
    }
}
```

There are no syntax errors or node errors, and all the physics work such as Rigidbody, the objects are just not visible. Then I realized I didn't have a prefab. So I made a prefab. Still the same issue. If you need any more information contact me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
mousePosition.z = 5f; // world position from the camera.
```

You should give a z position otherwise it is 0 which means the object is put at the position of the camera.

Comment: Ok, let me try that.